# Google form where all answer options calculate to 100%?

Tags: google-forms

Put the % of how much you spend of your salary in the following categories: [Airtravel, Rail transport, Taxi, Personal car, Uber ...., Other]

I want to format the question in Google Forms such that:

For each category, the user can input/select a value between 0%-100%
It should validate that the accumulation of the percentages is 100%
I tried Google Forms first, but I was unsuccessful. Any suggestions to do it using Google Forms?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Forms it's not possible to include a validation based on the response to several questions.

One alternative is to use Google Apps Script to do such validation after the form was submitted and in such case do something like send an email.